# Force SSL routes in Lumen 5.6

Tags: ssl, routes, lumen

I need to force all routes with SSL in Lumen 5.6.
For examples http://www.mywebsite.com to https://www.mywebsite.com

I tried many different solutions on the web, but nothing worked for me:
*Middelware*, *.htaccess*, *AppServiceProvider*

Which the best way to force SSL scheme in Lumen 5.6?

Comment: The best way is to do it at the webserver level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a middleware class and use the `redirect()->to` function with the `secure` parameter set to `true`.

To achieve this, create a class (`HttpsProtocol.php`) and place it in the middleware directory:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HttpsProtocol{

    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory|mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (!$request->secure() && app()->environment() === 'production') {
            return redirect()->to($request->getRequestUri(), 302, [], true);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

And add the middleware to your `$app->middleware` array found in `app.php`.

```
$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class
]);
```

Comment: Glad to hear, this should also work for v5.7 and v5.8.